# Django(2.11) simultaneous (within 10ms) identical HTTP requests

Tags: django, python-3.x, rest

Consider a POST/PUT REST API (using DRF).

If the server receives request1 and within a couple of ms request2 with identical everything to request1 (duplicate request), is there a way to avoid the request2 to be executed using some Django way? Or Should I deal with it manually by some state?

Any inputs would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything out of the box so you would need to write something your self potentially a piece of custom middleware (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/) would be best as then it would run over all of the requests. You would need to capture and exam the requests so you'd need a fast storage of some sort such as a memory store.

You could also look into the python asynco library - https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html

Another possible solution would be using a FIFO message queue which is configured to support de-duplication based on content. This would turn the request into an deferred process though so it may not be suitable for your needs.